# re.compile does not work properly

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find tag usin bs4, where text is in format: 'Firma: ...........'. The problem is that re.compile does not work for this at all. I can't find out what am I doing.

Here is the code of html:

```
<span class="date">
    Firma:
    <b>Agedr js</b>
</span>
```

Here is a code to find this tag:

```
re.DOTALL
attributes = soup.findAll('span', class_='date')
        for attribute in attributes: 
            if  attribute == re.compile('Firma: .*'):
                firma = attribute.text
                print firma
```

I suppose that I'm using some special character in the text 'Firma: ' but I can't find it.
Where can be the problem?

EDIT: 
Ways doesn't work:

I try `re.compile('Firma.*')`.

```
re.DOTALL
```

Switch `if attribute == ...` to if `attribute.contents[0] == ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is comparing the compiled pattern object with `Tag` object. It will always fail.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile('a') == 'a'  # PatternObject == str  => always false
False
>>> re.compile('a').search('a')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002933168>
>>> re.search('a', 'a')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x00000000029331D0>
```

You should use `PatternObject.search` (or `re.search`) with `str` (slight modified the pattern not to include space):

```
if re.compile('Firma:.*').search(attribute.text):
    firma = attribute.text
    print firma
```

But for this simple case, you'd better to use `in` operator:

```
if 'Firma:' in attribute.text:
    ....
```

Comment: Oh, I'm stupid, thanks. The second option will definitely works.

Comment: I've just realized, that I forgot to write '.text' after 'attribute' variable: 'attribute.text == re.compile('Firma: .*'):' which did not work too. But attribute.text is str as far as I'm concerned, so it should work as well but it did not.

Comment: @Mill, As I wrote in the answer, it will yield `False`. Regular expression pattern is not meant to be compared directly with string using `==` oeprator. It should be compared using `search`, `match` method. Or you can use `findall`, `finditer` to find matched strings.